# I want to delete a partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I want to dual boot windows 8 and linux so, i need to create a separate partition for linux. All i wanted on the new partition is 15gbs. My computer wont let me "shrink volume" to create the partition. I didn't even get a suggested amount to shrink the volume. I can put in my suggested amount but the "Shrink" button is greyed out. According to what i read on a few post it's because i already have 4 partitions? My question is can i delete any of the existing partitions without screwing up windows 8 boot system.

The site won't let be post any images since i'm new.

Anyways, the four partitions showing up in the disk management log are:

1. Healthy (Recovery Partition)    400mb capacity, 400mb free space.
2. Healthy (EFI System Partition)  100mb capacity, 100mb free space.
3. Healthy (Recovery Partition)    11.72gb capacity, 11.72gb free space.
4. ACER C/ (Healthy (Boot,Page File,Crash dump etc) 106.91gb capacity, 41.22gb free space.

Any suggestion is appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: Why you have a two recovery partitions?

Comment: I'm not sure why there's more than one recovery drive there avinash. That's how the system came with the pre-installed windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is currently possible to modify currently mounted partitions.

The easiest way to do this is to use the gparted tool on a live cd (or usb) to manage the partitions without mounting them.

Be aware, however, it is much easier to install windows 8 first, then install Ubuntu.  This way Grub will pick up both OS'es without you having to figure out how to manage your MBR.

This also has the added advantage of being able to resize your live active partition in Windows 8 without the need of a live cd.  This is possible using Windows 8's Disk Management tool.

Answer (score 0):

As lbaile200 said, Gparted will work great to repartition your drive. An amazing reference to installing alongside windows 8.
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html
Hope it helps!
Matt